# High ping on local server?

Tags: steam, pc, windows-7

I have been playing America's Army Proving Grounds for quite a while now and I have always played on international server with a ping of 300 to 500 which was very bad and laggy but I had no choice as there was no local servers for me to play on until about 2 months ago when a few local people hosted their own server.  I could then play with a ping of about 50 to 80 which was great.  I played like that for about 2 months until now when my ping is suddenly no lower than 250 on the local server I have been playing on all this time with a 50 to 80 ping.  I asked the host of the server if his ISP is having problems but he said no and that the ISP was fine.  I also did a lot of research about this but couldn't find anything that works for me.

Can someone please help me get my ping back to 50-80 on one of the local servers? I am out of ideas and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try pinging google.com and some local domains.

Comment: Okay I pinged Google and got a ping of 225 which is normal because i am in South Africa although when I tried to ping local domains it said request timed out.

Comment: If a ping of 225 is normal, I would recommend not hosting.

Comment: "Local" is a term that can mean one of two things in computer networking: either the server is running on your own computer (localhost) or on another computer directly connected to your computer (or via a router / switch). Anything else is "remote", not "local". It sounds like you aren't talking about local servers at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try running [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) (on Windows it is `tracert`) to the destination server. Then you will be able to pin down the exact point where the latency increases.

The latency to your router should be as low as a couple of milliseconds. If it is higher, then you have problems with your LAN. If you are on Wi-Fi, try improving the signal, or try using an ethernet cable instead.

The latency beyond your router is outside your control, so there is little you can do, other than complaining to the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Fellow South African!!
:) 
So basically the isp we have is really bad, I don't know your location so I can't help there. 
Basically when you said that pinging google responded with a ms of 225. Google servers redirect to the nearest server(We have a google hq in jozi by the way) So that leaves it at this. Your net. 
Check your isp, restart your router and so on. 
Best of luck